# Does a producer make multiple calls to schema registry when producing multiple messages

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We are using confluent schema registry to validate our avro schemas before publishing. I've two questions here,

1. Does a producer make multiple calls to schema registry when producing multiple messages ?
2. If it does, is it a HTTP/HTTPS call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is CACHE storage that producers and consumers have.
This cache stores the registered schema.

If you are sending multiple data and your cache has that schema so it makes no calls.
Only at the time of registering the schema, it makes calls to the Schema Registry to get the schema and add it to the Cache.

Answer (score 2):

It makes one call per schema, then caches it in memory while the application runs

The protocol depends on the URL you've configured, but it is HTTP by default